# Does anyonw have a script for adding sequential numbers (as a prefix) to layer names in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-scripting

I'm looking for a script that can add sequential numbers as a prefix to existing names of layers in Adobe Illustrator.

Does anyone here known of one? Or, could you direct me to where I may find one?

Thanks in advance,
Dave

Comment: Main level layers or sublayers also?

Comment: Yes, main layers is all I need. I just tried what you suggested and it worked great. However- it numbers the layers from the topmost (as viewed in the layers pallet) to the bottom-most layer. Is there a way to reverse this-- and have Zero be the bottom layer,.. and increase the numbers as I add layers?

Thank you for solving this for me-- and doing it so quickly. It will be VERY helpful with my work flows.

Comment: sure, just change the selection logic, added code.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this does the trick for you?

```
#target illustrator

var doc = app.activeDocument;
var layerCount = doc.layers.length;
for (var j = 0; j < layerCount; j++) {
    layer = doc.layers[j];
    layer.name = j.toString() + "_" + layer.name;
}
```

and same thing in reverse

```
#target illustrator

var doc = app.activeDocument;
var layerCount = doc.layers.length;
for (var j = 0; j < layerCount; j++) {
    layer = doc.layers[layerCount-1-j];
    layer.name = j.toString() + "_" + layer.name;
}
```

Comment: Awesome-- you ROCK!
Thanks for taking the time to assist me with this. It will be very helpful to me.

Comment: @dMisco if this solved your problem please accept the answer. It helps both me, you, the site and future visitors. You may wait to get more answers but dont forget to accept if you found a solution. You may even write your own answer.